# Harmonic sum with Dirichlet eta tail

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions, harmonic-numbers

The following problem is proposed by Cornel Valean:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{2n+1}\left(\eta(2)- \overline{H}_n^{(2)}\right)$$
$$=2 G^2-2\ln(2) \pi G+\ln^2(2)\frac{\pi ^2}{6}  +\frac{53}{1440}\pi ^4-\frac{1}{6} \ln ^4(2)-4 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
where $H_n^{(m)}=1+\frac{1}{2^m}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^m}, \ m\ge1$, is the $n$th generalized harmonic number of order $m$, $\overline{H}_n^{(m)}=1-\frac{1}{2^m}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^m}, \ m\ge1$, represents the $n$th generalized skew-harmonic number of order $m$, $G$  denotes the Catalan's constant, $\zeta$ designates the Riemann zeta function, $\eta$ designates the Dirichlet eta function, and $\operatorname{Li}_n$ signifies the Polylogarithm.

Here is my approach: Using
$$\eta(2)-\overline{H}_n^{(2)}=-\int_0^1\frac{(-x)^n\ln(x)}{1+x}dx$$

and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{2n+1}x^n=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-y^2x)}{1-y^2x}dy,$$

the sum converts to

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\ln(1+y^2x)}{(1+x)(1+y^2x)}dydx.$$
Any idea how to crack this integral or a different approach than mine?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A solution may be found in this short presentation, [Exploiting The Master Theorem of Series to Evaluate a Series with the Tail of the Dirichlet Eta Function Artistically](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/376392494), by **C.I. Valean**.

Another solution, as emphasized at the given link, may be obtained by exploiting
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1  x^{2n-1}\operatorname{arctanh}^2(x)\textrm{d}x=\log(2)\frac{H_{2n}}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)\frac{H_n}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{H_k}{2k+1},
\end{equation*}
which is given and derived in **More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series, Springer, Cham, First Edition (2023)**, more precisely in **Chapter 1**, **Section 1.22**, **p.29**.

**End of story** (apart from this, I would love to see more real solutions using very different ideas)

Comment: Ali, even if you like this answer, please don't choose it yet - let it go like that for months, maybe more people are motivated to work hard on this problem.

Comment: Very nice solutions. Sure I'll wait for more answers. (+1)

Comment: Thank you, Ali.